# C++11's "const==mutable", non-const == unprotected == efficient when needed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, mutable

As I introduced also in this question, [C++11's "const==mutable", Provide two classes for efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143468/c11-saga-of-const-mutable-provide-two-classes-for-efficiency) ,
in C++98, or before threads, albeit incorrect in some contexts, it was common to write class with internal hidden using mutable.

In C++11 Herb Sutter said that from now on `const == thread safe`, meaning that the the mutable fields should be protected by a mutex.

so I though that some one that really know what he/she is doing can actually a more general version of the single class by doing something special in the non-const case.

```cpp
struct Widget {
private:
  int getValue_aux() const{
    if (cacheValid) return cachedValue;
    else {
      cachedValue = expensiveQuery(); // write data mem
      cacheValid = true;                    // write data mem
      return cachedValue;
    }
  }
public:
  int getValue() {
    return get_value_aux();  // no lock
  }                                    
  int getValue() const{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{m}; // lock mutex
    get_value_aux();
  }                                      // unlock mutex
...
  private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  mutable int cachedValue;
  mutable bool cacheValid;
...
};
```

So, a) a normal user can use a non-const instance of `Widget` to *mark* that it is not intended to be used in a thread safe context, and not pay for the mutex-locking b) A user-that-really-knows-what-he-is-doing can `const_cast` or wrap it as `mutable` if he knows that thread safety is not going to be an issue on a particular point in the code (he/she is still storing a mutex though).

**Is this a reasonable generalization of Widget at all? Or is it flawed?**

---

Note: If you think that `const` and non-`const` versions should be provided for efficiency, you may find this question also interesting: [C++11's "const==mutable", How to implement copy? efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143607/c11-saga-of-const-mutable-how-to-implement-copy-and-efficiently)