# C++11's "const==mutable", How to implement copy? efficiently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, mutable

As I introduced in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143468/c11-saga-of-const-mutable-provide-two-classes-for-efficiency) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143433/c11-saga-of-const-mutable-non-const-unprotected-efficient-when-you-need) , it seem that the modern way to implement a thread safe class with hidden state is this:

```
struct Widget {
  int getValue() const{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{m}; // lock mutex
    if (cacheValid) return cachedValue;
    else {
      cachedValue = expensiveQuery(); // write data mem
      cacheValid = true;                    // write data mem
      return cachedValue;
    }
  }                                      // unlock mutex
...
  private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  mutable int cachedValue;
  mutable bool cacheValid;
...
};
```

The logic seems solids and explained here: https://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/

The question is how do I implement the *rest* of the class?
In particular the copy constructor.

One option is not to implement copy and that's it. (`=delete`).
But `Widget` can have bonafide state (in `...`) and that state should be copyable or one might want to make copies precisely to alleviate the usage of a *single* mutex and balance it with the expense of `expensiveQuery`.

So lets assume we want to make `Widget` copyable: one cannot make it default-copyable because the mutex is not copyable so something needs to be implemented manually.

This is already complicated because one needs to protect the source instance `other` *before* copying and for that one seems to need a body for the function.

```cpp
struct Widget {
  Widget(Widget const& other){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{other.m}; // lock mutex
     cachedValue = other.cachedValue;
     cachedValid = other.cachedValid;
  }
  ...
};
```

This is getting very ugly.
Maybe one needs to implement a `lock()` function that RAII-lock and return the unprotected `Widget_nonmt`, this is possible but you can see how the problem diverges.

**Is this the right way to make the C++11 `Widget` copyable?**

Finally, we can have a user complaining that now he/she is being forced  me to use the mutex for copies even in context that I know they are unnecessary.

And this is where it gets crazy, continuing with this logic (same as for the member function) one might think of introducing a non-const copy constructor.

```cpp
struct Widget{
  Widget(Widget& other) : cachedValid{other.cachedValid}, cachedValue{other.cachecValue}{}
  Widget(Widget const& other) ... // same as above
};
```

Note that this is not a move constructor, it is something more strange.
(something like the doomed `std::auto_ptr`)

It is not unusable, but is very non-standard and for example the STL containers for example will never use when copying containers of `Widget`.

Logic took me to this ugly place, starting from something solid.
Is this a problem that still waits for a more elegant and general solution?

**Is this the real end of C++98 to C++11 transition saga of a class with protected internal state?**